# How to pass more than one parameter to python map function?

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

I am trying to use the map function on a list of list. How do you pass each distance to map function. If you see below code it caluculated the distances and returns a output as a list.

```
import math
locations = [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
distance = lambda x,y : math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
output = list(map(distance, locations))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Comment: Firstly, note that `list(map(...))` is [discouraged](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists); read up on list comprehensions. Secondly, map will always pass the whole sublist to the lambda, as that's the element within the outer list.

Comment: See [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap)

Comment: `lambda x : math.sqrt(x[0]**2 + x[1]**2)`  would be one way - but using a `loc_squared = [math.sqrt(x*x+y*y) for x,y in locations]` should do it as well  ... or use Patrick Haugh's suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on all answers, my solution is below

```
import math
import itertools
locations = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
output = list(itertools.starmap(lambda x,y: math.sqrt(x**2  + y**2), locations))
```

I am sending those computed values to another function, so in my case I think, storing it in a list is the only option.

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
import math
locations = [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
distance = lambda x,y : math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
output = list(map(distance, *locations))
```

Comment: it would be great for others if your provide more info on that *locations operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `math.hypot` function instead of writing your own:

```
import math
import itertools
locations = (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)
print(*itertools.starmap(math.hypot, locations), sep='\n')
```

Please use `itertools.starmap` if you want to have something other than two locations.

Comment: any best practices to store it as list ? It looks like using `list(*itertools.starmap(math.hypot, locations))` is not a good practice

Comment: @ajayramesh That depends on what you are going to do with the data after processing it. If you are going to look at it once, then you are right; storing the results in a list (or a tuple) is not the best choice. You should simply be iterating over it instead. If on the other hand you plan on looking at the processed data several times, then storing it in a list or a tuple (or other storage structure) should be preferred. Without seeing more of your code, it is difficult to help anymore than that.